# scala - if/else in a for loop

Tags: scala, loops, for-loop, if-statement

If i use the two for loops like this i get a List[List[Int]], but how can i get a List[Int]?
I dont know how i could write a if/else statement in only one for loop, can someone help me ?

```
def example:  (List[(Int, Int)], Int,Int) => List[Int] ={
    (list, p, counter) => 
    if (counter >=0)
        for(x<-list(i._1); if ( x._1 ==p))yield x._2
        for(x<-list(i._1); if ( x._1 !=p))yield example((x._1,x._2+i._2):: Nil,p,counter-1)
    else { ....}
}
```

Comment: the syntax is not correct, did you try to run the function you wrote?

Comment: it doesnt work beacuse of the return, thats why i want to change it but i dont know how

Comment: pleas see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @user10027527 can you post whole code for us, like what is present in else statement, also can you also post an example input for the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as written, the code you posted is not even a valid definition. If you have something that works but returns a different type than what is desired, post that working code.

That being said, if you have `List[List[Int]]` and want a `List[Int]`, the method for that is `flatten`

Usage:

```
scala> val nestedList = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5, 6))
nestedList: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5, 6))

scala> val flattenedList = nestedList.flatten
flattenedList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```